# Rounded corners with transparency with ImageResizer.NET

Tags: imageresizer

When using the `roundcorners` setting on the [simple filters plugin](http://imageresizing.net/docs/v3/plugins/simplefilters) - is it possible to have the background color be set to transparent (as opposed to white)? If so, how?

For reference, my present looks like this:

```
<preset name="roundedthumb" settings="s.roundcorners=100;mode=crop;width=100;height=100" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here...

The source image I was testing on was in jpeg format (which doesn't support transparency).

The solution was simply to force the output format to png (which supports transparencies natively).

My new present looks like this:

```
<preset name="roundedthumb" settings="s.roundcorners=100;mode=crop;width=100;height=100;format=png" />
```